# SOLVED - Error on new contribute after upgrade to 5.41.2

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

After upgrading to 5.41.2 I have a problem when creating a new contribute.
Any suggestion in order to manage the error?

error log:

```
Versione di WordPress 5.8.1
Plugin corrente: CiviCRM (versione 5.41.2)
Versione PHP 7.4.23



Dettagli dell'errore
====================
Un errore di E_ERROR è stato causato nella linea 390 del file /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php. Messaggio di errore: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::isOverrideLineItemFinancialType() must be of the type int, null given, called in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php on line 817 and defined in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php:390
Stack trace:
#0 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php(817): CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->isOverrideLineItemFinancialType(NULL)
#1 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php(700): CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->calculateLineItems()
#2 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php(926): CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->getLineItems()
#3 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php(1600): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution::formRule(Array, Array, Object(CRM_Contri
```

Other log

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceSet.php on line 1633

Notice: Undefined index: in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/LineItem.php on line 311

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/LineItem.php on line 311

Notice: Undefined index: in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/LineItem.php on line 313

Notice: Undefined index: in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/LineItem.php on line 331

Notice: Undefined index: in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Price/BAO/PriceSet.php on line 1637

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::isOverrideLineItemFinancialType() must be of the type int, null given, called in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php on line 817 and defined in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php:390 Stack trace: #0 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php(817): CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->isOverrideLineItemFinancialType(NULL) #1 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php(700): CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->calculateLineItems() #2 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php(926): CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->getLineItems() #3 /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm.php(1600): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution::formRule(Array, Array, Object(CRM_Contri in /home/gragorg/staging.grag.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Financial/BAO/Order.php on line 390
```

Answer (score 1):

After two day of try and error I got the problem: the new version get from the keypad as decimal separator the . instead the , and civicrm doesn't manage it. Also if I put only the integer part of without the decimal part it assume the .
I'm not sure if there something different in the new version about regional settings, but I'm happy to have solve it

Comment: Ah good job. There was https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2756 but it looks like it was fixed already, and I don't see the problem on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

Comment: I have this problem with 5.41.2 and also with the last release 5.42.1 :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a line item that doesn't have a financial type. Check your financial types and if using price sets check the financial types on them.

Comment: I have just a priceset, and if I use it the system works fine. The financial type seems good (the related table is very simple) and I try to save again it without any success, the problem occurs with all the financial types. How could I check if the data is not correct?

Comment: I have a log with more information htat add to the question

Comment: Could it be related to negative contribution? I use this type of contribute in order to manage costs